# Set possible parameters for numpy curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I want to fit data in python using the curve_fit function. For that I am using the basic functions

```
def a(x):
    return x*x

def b(x):
    return x*x*x
```

and combine them into multiple functions:

```
def fit_func(x, n1, n2, n3):
    return n1*a(x)+n2*b(x)+n3*a(x)
```

Now I was wondering if there is a way to write such a function:

```
def fit_multi_func(x, n1, b1, n2, b2, n3, b3):
    tmp = 0
    if(b1 == 1):
        tmp += n1*a(x)
    else:
        tmp += n1*b(x)
    if(b2 == 1):
        tmp += n2*a(x)
    else:
        tmp += n2*b(x)
    if(b3 == 1):
        tmp += n3*a(x)
    else:
        tmp += n3*b(x)
```

and I tell `curve_fit` that it can set `b1`, `b2` and `b3` either to `1` or `0`. Of course another possibility is to create separate functions for each combination out of `a(x)` and `b(x)`, but that is blowing up fast if I have not only three parameters and two functions, but more. Or is there another simpler way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to fit bi = 0 or 1 in addition to the coefficients ni? Or you want to set bi before the fit and float only those ni which have bi=1?

Comment: What I want: I want to give `curve_fit` a function consisting out of several sub-functions. Those sub-functions can be exchanged, i.e. can either be `a(x)` or `b(x)`, but `curve_fit` should decide which subfunctions it wants to use in the fitting function.

Comment: I'm not sure that `curve_fit` will do this for you (i.e. constrain `b` to be 1 or 0). But would you not generally expect the best fit to your curve to involve all your functions (all bi=1)?

Comment: According to my code the function should consist out of `n1*b(x)+n2*b(x)+n3*b(x)` if all `b`-values are zero, and out of `n1*a(x)+n2*a(x)+n3*a(x)` if all `b`-values are ones (including mixed results). Therefore I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, there is not enough information in your data to solve for all the parameters you are interested in.  Consider the simple case where you have

```
n1*a(x) + n2*a(x)
```

Say the inputs are `n1, n2 = (1, 1)`. Then an equally valid output is `n1, n2 = (0, 2)` or `n1, n2 = (-1000000, 1000002)` or any other in an infinite number of exact solutions along the line `n1 + n2 = 2`.

This is known as a *degenerate model*, and the best way forward is probably to re-express your problem as, e.g. `f(x) = n1 * a(x) + n2 * b(x)` and solve for `n1` and `n2`. It won't give you the solution in the form you desire, but the form you desire has an infinite space of equivalent solutions and will not fare well with any solver.

Comment: The problem is that my functions are not that easy as displayed above, I have a gaussian function and a lorentzian function, which are not exchangable as in your example. Therefore I was looking for a solution where the solver decides if he should use `a` or `b`.

Comment: My comments stand regardless of the function. Whatever ``f(x)`` is, there will not be a unique solution to ``n1 * f(x) + n2 * f(x) + n3 * f(x)``.